# Отправка значения поля vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку с Vue.js, третий день мучаюсь... готов отблагодарить индивидуально

Есть массив данных с базы, который выводится циклом, мне нужно чтоб каждое поле при клике можно было отредактировать и записать значение опять же в базу, но чтоб понять какое поле редактируется мне нужно передать id и значение через axios, к примеру id: age, name: name и так для каждого поля.

```
<div class="card" v-for="user in users">
   <div class="card-body">
      <h4 v-if="!showInput" id="age" class="card-title" @click="showInput = true">{{ user.age }}</h4>
      <input v-else type="text" v-model="user.age" @blur="showInput = false">
   </div>
</div>

<script>
        data() {
            return{              
                showInput: false,
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/grinat/1jurdf86/2/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="card" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 v-if="!showInput" class="card-title" @click="showInput = true">{{ user.age }}</h4>
      <input v-else type="text" v-model="user.age" @blur="showInput = false">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button @click="save()">Save</button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [],
    showInput: false,
  },
  mounted () {
     this.fetchData().then(users => {
       this.users = [...users]
     })
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
       return Promise.resolve([
         {id: 10, age: 30},
         {id: 11, age: 45}
       ])
    },
    save () {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.users))
      axios.post('/save', this.users)
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/4gyjq3ob/92/)

После нажатия на кнопку можно изменить поля.

Вынес карточку в отдельный компонент.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('userCard', {
 template: `
 <div class="card">
  <img :src="userData.avatar" class="card-img-top" alt="">
  <div class="card-body">
   <input class="card-title" type="text" v-model="userData.name" :readonly="!editing">
   <input class="card-text" type="number" v-model="userData.age" :readonly="!editing">
   
   <div class="row px-3 justify-content-between">
    <button
     v-if="!editing"
     class="col-12 btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block"
     @click="toggleEditing()"
    >
     Изменить данные
    </button>
    
    <button
     v-if="editing"
     class="col-5 btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block"
     @click="cancelEdit()"
    >
     Отменить
    </button>
    
    <button
     v-if="editing"
     class="col-5 btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"
     @click="save()"
    >
     Сохранить
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 `,
 props: {
  user: Object
 },
 data() {
  return {
   editing: false,
   userData: {}
  }
 },
 created() {
  this.userData = Object.assign({}, this.user);
 },
 methods: {
  toggleEditing(state = undefined) {
   this.editing = state !== undefined ? state : !this.editing;
  },
  cancelEdit() {
   this.userData = Object.assign({}, this.user);
   this.toggleEditing(false);
  },
  save() {
   const params = {
    id: this.userData.id,
    name: this.userData.name,
    age: this.userData.age
   };
   axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', params).then(response => {
    alert(response.data.data);
    this.toggleEditing(false);
   }).catch(() => {});
  }
 }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
 users: [
  { 
   id: 0,
   name: 'Alex',
   avatar: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/280/180.jpg',
   age: 10
  },
  {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Billie',
   avatar: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/2/280/180.jpg',
   age: 17
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Piter',
   avatar: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/3/280/180.jpg',
   age: 20
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Greg',
   avatar: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/4/280/180.jpg',
   age: 12
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   name: 'John',
   avatar: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/5/280/180.jpg',
   age: 15
  },
 ]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.body {
 background: #20262E;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 padding: 25px 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

input {
 outline: none;
}

#app {
 border-radius: 4px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}

.card .card-title,
.card .card-text {
 border: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.card .card-title {
 margin-bottom: .75rem;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.card .card-text {
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.card button {
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="body">
 <div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div
    class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4"
    v-for="user in users"
    :key="user.id"
   >
    <user-card :user="user" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```